# Printing a selected value in the drop down list using php?

Tags: php, html

I have trying to print the selected value in the drop down list, but in vain. I am new to php and html, so this might sound like a stupid question but please help me out! this is my code:

```
echo '<tr><td>Client:</td><td><select name="client_name">';   
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client");
            $s= mysql_query("SELECT project.client_id, client_name, client.client_id FROM client,project where project.client_id=client.client_id AND project_id='$editId'");
          //  $s2= mysql_fetch_array($s);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
               while ($s2==mysql_fetch_array($s))
               { 
                if ($row['client_id'] == $s2['client_id'])
                 $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
                   else
                        $selected = " ";                                                                         
               }     
               echo '<option value="' . $row['client_id'] . '" ' . ($selected == $row['client_id'] ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $s2['client_name'] . '</option>';
            }
```

This code doesnt work. Please help me out! Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: "*This code doesnt work.*" isn't very helpful. What is it doing and what should it be doing?

Comment: $s2 seems to be not initialized. check your code again, and upload it commented please

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo '<tr><td>Client:</td><td><select name="client_name">';   
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client");
        $s= mysql_query("SELECT project.client_id, client_name, client.client_id FROM client,project where project.client_id=client.client_id AND project_id='$editId'");
      //  $s2= mysql_fetch_array($s);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
           while ($s2==mysql_fetch_array($s))
           { 
            if ($row['client_id'] == $s2['client_id'])
             $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
               else
                    $selected = " ";                                                                         
           }     
           echo '<option value="' . $row['client_id'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $s2['client_name'] . '</option>';
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is a problem

```
$s= mysql_query("SELECT project.client_id, client_name, client.client_id FROM client,project where project.client_id=client.client_id AND project_id='$editId'");
```

you are trying to get two client ids project.client_id and client.client_id, in such cases you should give aliases like project.client_id as project_client_id and client.client_id as client_client_id, then use that value to compare in while loop.

Note use whichever client id you want either project_client_id or client_client_id.